# Jquery String Format Replacement

Tags: jquery, font-size

Throughout a website (without using spans/divs/id tags), how would one modify the following code such that all instances of H2O are written so that the 2 is written in a smaller font. This code currently modifies all instances of the number 2 on the whole page -- I just want to search and replace only the 2's that are written in H2O throughout the whole site.

```
$('body :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.replace(/[2]/g, '<font size="-1">2</font>');
});
```

Comment: Does `.replace(/H2O/g, 'H<font size="-1">2</font>O');` work?

Comment: Use this markup instead H<sub>2</sub>O

Comment: The above code worked, thanks! One wrinkle... When the original text is in other tags, eg, H1, the 2 is actually quite small. Therefore, I need the font-size to always be 0.8em, but putting font size="0.8em" doesn't work. What's the proper syntax here to always make the 2 slightly smaller than the parent's text size?

Comment: Answered my own question: Should be 
`nodeValue.replace(/X2O/g, 'X<span style="font-size:0.8em">2</span>O');`

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.html(function(index, html){})` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/H20/`

```js
$("body *:not(script)").html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/H20/, "H<font size=-1>2</font>0")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>H20 abc</div>
<span>def H20 h20 2</span>
```